# What's the earliest point in which I can get the screen width using Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a function I'm binding on:

```
angular.module('app').directive('resizable', function($window) {
    return function(scope) {
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                //console.log($window.innerWidth);
                scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;
            });
        })
    }
});
```

But this doesn't fire on `onload`. I need the initial screen width upon page load. How do I get this using Angular?

UPDATE:

I've also tried this ...

```
angular.module('ccsApp').directive('setSize',
    ['$document', function($document) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, elements, attrs) {
                $document.on("load", function() {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        console.log('initial=');
                    });
                });
            }
        }}
    ]
);
```

Comment: Where is this code in the first place?

Comment: I posted an update JB, but this code doesn't trigger on an onload event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is in a directive. So you probably don't want the function to be executed when the application is loaded, but only when this directive is used. So, simply execute the function directly in the directive function:

```
angular.module('app').directive('resizable', function($window) {
    return function(scope) {
        // define the function
        var updateWindowWidth = function() {
            // console.log($window.innerWidth);
            scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth
        };

        // call it immediately to initialize the scope variable as soon as the directive is used
        updateWindowWidth();

        // and make sure it's called every time the window is resized
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
            scope.$apply(updateWindowWidth);
        });
    };
});
```

You should probably also make sure that the event handler is unbound when the directive is destroyed. Otherwise, every time the directive is used, an additional handler is added to the window.

Comment: I was trying to simulate an onload event using a directive. Is there a way to fire a function on an onload event? I'm trying to grab the screen's width when the page loads ... but thanks, this helps too!

Comment: AFAIK, the window event has been fired already when a directive is executed. Have you tried axecuting the above code? If so, is there a problem? If so which one? What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This works really well JB, but one minor issue is that the resize binding is triggered twice every time I adjust the screen. It only gets triggered once on a page load though.

Comment: Here's a good example of the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/spacm/HeMZP/

You can see that resize fires twice in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You could inject $window into a .run function of your module. Although there would be no scope available.

It is unclear what your are trying to do with the window size so our ability to provide helpful answers is limited

Comment: I'm trying to calculate screen width so that I can determine a column count. Afterwards, I invoke a function - which was getting invoked twice. But I was able to resolve this by checking my new calculation against an old stored value so now it doesn't matter how many times resize is triggered. This appears to be a problem in a lot of browsers upon more comprehensive research - the resize twice issue that is. Thanks for your help.